# SqlDependencyEx event inside Controller not getting fired

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, sqldependency, sqldependencyex

I´m trying to use SqlDependencyEx the problem is that the OnDataChange event is not getting fired inside the controller, I already enabled Service Broker. Here´s is the code:

```
    private const string CONNECTION_STRING = "Server=LFTCMCPTP83;Database=Database;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true; Integrated Security=false;User ID=used_id;Password=password";
    private const string DATABASE_NAME = "db_name";
    private const string TABLE_NAME = "table_name";
    private const string SCHEMA_NAME = "dbo";
    private SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(CONNECTION_STRING, DATABASE_NAME,
    TABLE_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME);
    private void RegisterNotification()
    {
        sqlDependency.TableChanged += OnDataChange;
        sqlDependency.Start();
    }
    private void OnDataChange(object sender, SqlDependencyEx.TableChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Code
    }
    public IActionResult Create(){
         RegisterNotification();
    }
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, here´s the code:

```
private const string CONNECTION_STRING = "Server=LFTCMCPTP83;Database=Database;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true; Integrated Security=false;User ID=used_id;Password=password";
private const string DATABASE_NAME = "db_name";
private const string TABLE_NAME = "table_name";
private const string SCHEMA_NAME = "dbo";
private SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(CONNECTION_STRING, DATABASE_NAME,
TABLE_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME);
listener.TableChanged += (o, args) =>
{
   //Code...
};
listener.Start();
listener.Stop();
```

Best Regards